# How to understand 'and these too we will include under the concept of theme.'?

Tags: meaning

> But the difference between these is of no significance for more
> general roles, and these too we will include under the concept of
> theme.

Could it be changed to 'and these we will include under the concept of theme too.'?

I recognize these as a kind of stress.

Comment: Imho moving ***too*** to the *end* of the sentence in your example would be a stylistically poor choice. There would be too much text between the "referent" (***these** = more general roles*) and the "qualifier" (*they're **additional**, them **too***). That places an unwelcome / unnecessary burden on the reader. But the utterance is badly phrased anyway, because the two different instances of ***these*** obviously refer to ***different things***, which is pointlessly distracting.  An "easier" (better) phrasing would be ***...which** we will **also** include under the concept of theme*.

Answer (score -1):

"Too" is generally used to add emphasis or to indicate that something is an additional feature or aspect of something else. It's a flexible word that can be placed in different positions within a sentence. You can check the explanation from Cambridge dictionary.
[image]

Comment: Not about the usage of too,but the preposition of 'these too'. Also ,thanks.